# How do I prevent minimize (via SCIPY) from outputting "optimized" parameters that I have input as guesses?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, distribution, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I am trying to use the [minimize function from the scipy module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). The full code is too lengthy to post, but the main idea is that there are multiple defined distributions that should be fittable against datasets. The observations per bin are easily calculated from the datasets, whereas the expectations per bin are calculated by a function that uses one argument to specify which distribution should be integrated over bin bounds (where the bin bounds are identical to the histogram bins). There are three functions chisqI where I = 1,2,3 (one for each distribution), each of which inputs specified observations per bin and expectations per bin to output the chi square. Then there are three functions, each of which inputs a chisqI and args to output the minimized function result and optimized parameters. Here, the args are parameters mu and sigma that will be optimized to produce the smallest chi-square. I was able to pass arguments through a chain of functions for one distribution, and am wondering if I need to pass through another arg that specifies which distribution is being dealt with from one function down the chain.

There are different methods that the minimize function can use, like Nelder-Mead or CG. I've been trying to compare results from the different methods to find the one that provides the best fit (where the best fit is defined as the fit that both produces the smallest chi-square or largest p-value when compared to an actual dataset). Interestingly enough, the Nelder-Mead and Powell methods produce the lowest chi square relative to the other methods, but the plotted fit against the histogram of the actual data looks better with other methods. For the code outputs below, the function value is the negative of the p-value that is associated with a chi-square value; this is the minimized result. `CHISQ_RED` is the reduced chi square value by using the `CHISQ_TOT` and the degrees of freedom, whereas the first and second elements in the `x: array` are the optimized parameters mu and sigma for a distribution, respectively.

Running the Nelder-Mead minimization method produces the output below.

```
 final_simplex: (array([[ 6.00002802,  0.60020636],
       [ 5.99995429,  0.60018798],
       [ 6.0000716 ,  0.60011127]]), array([ -5.16845821e-21,  -5.16838926e-21,  -5.16815050e-21]))
           fun: -5.1684582072826815e-21
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 47
           nit: 24
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 6.00002802,  0.60020636])

CHISQ_TOT =  259.042420419 CHISQ_RED =  3.36418727816
```

Running the CG minimization method produces the output below.

```
     fun: -4.0964504680695594e-97
     jac: array([  8.72867710e-94,  -3.96555507e-93])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 4
     nit: 0
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 6.01921293,  0.54436257])

CHISQ_TOT =  683.781671477 CHISQ_RED =  8.88028144776
```

Yet, the fit with a [higher chi square value looks like a better fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rplrb.png) (same dataset in the histogram).

The problem is that every method of minimization outputs my guess parameters (mu and sigma) as the optimized parameters. The Nelder-Mead method (smaller chi-square, worse-looking fit) has 47 function evaluations and 24 iterations, whereas the CG method (larger chi-square, better-looking fit) has 4 function evaluations and 0 iterations. I tried to change this by adding extra args in the minimization function (where `chisq3` is the pre-defined function of mu and sigma being minimized, and `parameterguess` is `[mu_guess, sigma_guess]`.

```
minimize( chisq3 , parameterguess , method = 'CG', options={'gtol':1e-50, 'maxiter': 100})
```

If I change my guess value of mu and sigma by adding 2 to each, then the fits become drastically worse (as the guess value for the optimized parameters is rather decent). I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the data shown in the plots are adapted from a lognormal distribution by taking the logarithm of each value in my dataset to create a "pseudo-" Gaussian shape/distribution (over logarithmic x axes).

I am guessing that the minimize function via scipy is supposed to do many iterations to be *truly* successful. So I think adding more iterations should decrease the sensitivity of the minimize function to my initial guess of parameters.

Most importantly, is this a common error using the minimize function via scipy? If so, what are some common fixes for this? Also, why would the minimize function do many iterations and function evaluations only to produce the same result as the input?

Comment: Probably not much help here without code. The text is also kind of hard to follow. ```I am guessing that the minimize function via scipy is supposed to do many iterations to be truly successful. So I think adding more iterations should decrease the sensitivity of the minimize function to my initial guess of parameters.``` - this indicates a deep misunderstanding of the optimization methods you are using here. This behaviour would maybe fit Metaheuristics, but not highly-formalized algorithms in use here (which at least try to achieve local convergence).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that chi square is the calculation equalto the sum of the square of the per-bin difference of expectation values and observed values, all divided by the expectation value. The result was a small number divided by a large number, squared, then continuously summed thousands of times, contributing to zero division problems and round off errors. By minimizing a simpler function, such as chi square without the denominator term, the source of the bug is gone and one can calculate a chi square from the obtained parameter fit.